# Porting flask ASK to bare metal Linux

Tags: linux, pip, alexa-skills-kit, openembedded, flask-ask

I am trying to port the Flask ask to a baremetal running custom linux (based on [Openembedded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEmbedded))  . The actual [documentation](https://flask-ask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) says

```
pip install Flask
```

But on my bare metal system  there is not even pip.

SO I have to cross compile pip for my system ([The Python Package Installer](https://github.com/pypa/pip))

I want to know is pip the only way to install the flask ask. Can we cross build the flask ask and run it on any platform?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to install flask-ask using PIP, you can always try installing via source.

1. Download the flask-ask folder from git hub. https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask
2. Unzip and CD into the folder contain setup.py
3. Run `python setup.py install`

You may need administrator privileges for step 3. What you do here thus depends on your operating system. For example in Ubuntu you would say `sudo python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

First, you can install `pip3` easily, the recipe is `python3-pip`.

There's already a recipe for Flask itself: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/45374/.  Following that example, writing a new recipe for flask-ask should be fairly trivial.

Comment: I think the question is on flask ask and not the flask ( web dev framework). Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You're right, the documentation link goes to flask-ast but the pip install line is Flask the web framework.